# Search Bar issue, Can not re-search VB 2008

Tags: vb.net

Well I'm creating a search bar to find some patients in my school project, but when I search it works, but when I made another search it sent me the message as if the number dont exist even when it exist, this is the code of the button hope you can help me.

```
Private Sub cmdIDBuscar_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdBuscarID.Click

    Dim sqlCon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim sqlComm As New SqlClient.SqlCommand

    'Ruta de la conección.
    sqlCon.ConnectionString = ("Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Sistema para Hospitales.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True")
    'Instrucción con la que se trabajara.
    sqlComm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Pacientes] WHERE IDPaciente= '" & txtID.Text & "';"
    'Abrir la coneccion SQL
    sqlCon.Open()

    Do Until txtID.Text = txtCompararID.Text

        Me.PacientesBindingSource.MoveNext()

        Exit Do

        If EOF(True) Then KryptonMessageBox.Show("Error, no se encontro paciente.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

    Loop

    If txtID.Text = txtCompararID.Text Then
        txtNombres.Text = txtCompararN1.Text & " " & txtCompararN2.Text & " " & txtCompararN3.Text
        txtApellidos.Text = txtCompararAp1.Text & " " & txtCompararAp2.Text
        txtEdad.Text = txtCompararEdad.Text
        Select Case txtCompararSexo.Text
            Case Is = "F"
                txtSexo.Text = "Femenino"
            Case Is = "M"
                txtSexo.Text = "Masculino"
        End Select
        Select Case TipoAfiliacionTextBox.Text
            Case Is = "1"
                txtTAfiliacion.Text = "Cotizante"
            Case Is = "2"
                txtTAfiliacion.Text = "Beneficiario"
            Case Is = "3"
                txtTAfiliacion.Text = "Pensionado"
        End Select
        txtAltura.Text = AlturaTextBox1.Text
        txtPeso.Text = PesoTextBox1.Text
        txtPresion.Text = PresionTextBox.Text
        txtTemperatura.Text = TemperaturaTextBox.Text
    Else
        KryptonMessageBox.Show("No se encontro el paciente", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: "[...] sent me the message as if the number dont exist even when it exist". What is the "message"? What is the "number"?

Comment: Well sorry for this, what I mean is that, it send me the messagebox that says "Patient didn't found". and the number is the Id, with the one I identify all the patients, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among other problems, because you have an Exit Do statement in the middle of your comparison loop, you will probably only ever match the first record since your do loop will execute a maximum of one time.

I am guessing that txtCompararID is databaound to your PacientesBindingSource and that the intent of your loop is move through this binding source until you find the value that matches txtID.

If that is the case, your do loop should look something more like:

```
' Get back to the top of the list
Me.PacientesBindingSource.MoveFirst()

Do Until txtID.Text = txtCompararID.Text

    Me.PacientesBindingSource.MoveNext()

    If EOF(True) Then 
       KryptonMessageBox.Show("Error, no se encontro paciente.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.AbortRetryIgnore, MessageBoxIcon.Error)

       Exit Do
    End If
Loop
```

In addition, you should use Using statements for your connection and command objects so that they are properly closed and disposed of when you are done using them.

For example:

```
Using sqlCon As New SqlClient.SqlConnection
Using sqlComm As New SqlClient.SqlCommand

... all of your code
End Using
End Using
```

And finally, and most importantly, you should be using a parameterized query statement in order to prevent SQL injection attacks since you are allowing direct entry of values. This statement:

```
sqlComm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Pacientes] WHERE IDPaciente= '" & txtID.Text & "';"
```

should be changed to something like:

```
sqlComm.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [Pacientes] WHERE IDPaciente= ?"
sqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("IDPaciente", txtID.text)
```

Comment: Well let me tell you that I already try something like that, the code of the loop, but it sent me a error that says: bad file name er number.

Comment: Complementing the idea before, it sent me the message in the If seccion